# Elasticsearch memory usage of fielddata

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I created a simple autocomplete using ElasticSearch following the article http://www.bilyachat.com/2015/07/search-like-google-with-elasticsearch.html.

The below is a simple example.
https://gist.github.com/jinkyou/ac92c0d9fc53860b703ac773af03b0da

At first, I didn't set `"fielddata": true` to the autocomplete property.
Then ES returned an error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [autocomplete] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
      }
}
```

So, I added `"fielddata": true` to the property of autocomplete and it works fine.

But after the documents are increased, `[fielddata] Data too large, data for [autocomplete] would be larger than limit of [249416908/237.8mb]]` error occurred.

Here's the my questions.

**Is it a right way to implement 'autocomplete'?**

I though it's a common function of search engine, but there is no suggester for it in ES. Am I right?

**Is 'fielddata' is necessary for this function?**

I think even it's not necessary for the function, I need it to response in short time.

**How can I reduce fielddata size? or increase fielddata limit size?**

I'm gonna try to decrease `max_shingle_size`. If there is any other good way, please let me know.

**What is the real memory usage of ES**

I want to figure out memory consumption following document size, but the result of `GET _nodes/stats` contains strange things that

```
{
  "os": {
    "mem": {
      "total_in_bytes": 128922271744,
      "free_in_bytes": 2966560768,
      "used_in_bytes": 125955710976,
      "free_percent": 2,
      "used_percent": 98
    }
  }
}
```

I just turn on the ES and there is no index but it shows almost memories are in use.

Thank you so much to read this.